# Elasticsearch - get child documents of (get parent documents which has hit in child documents)

Tags: elasticsearch, search, parent-child

This is my first post on stackoverflow!

I'm new to elasticsearch and I'm trying build search query for my complex scenario.

Here is index and data setup.

I have created index using below template.

```
PUT /files
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "docid": { "type": "long" },
        "parentdocid": { "type": "long" },
        "name": {"type":"text"},
        "info": {"type":"text"}
      }
    }
}
```

Inserted below data

```
POST /files/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{ "docid" : 1, "parentdocid": 0, "name": "apple", "info": "file 1" }
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{ "docid" : 2, "parentdocid": 0, "name": "microsoft", "info": "file 2" }
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{ "docid" : 3, "parentdocid": 2, "name": "minit", "info": "child 1 of file 2" }
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{ "docid" : 4, "parentdocid": 2, "name": "oribi", "info": "child 2 of file 2" }
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{ "docid" : 5, "parentdocid": 1, "name": "primephonic", "info": "child 1 of file 1" }
```

Here is scenario

I want to build query that can get all child documents which have same parent with any one or more child document has query hit.
So if I search for "minit" term in index then I want result as below

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "files",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.5897495,
        "_source" : {
          "docid" : 3,
          "parentdocid" : 2,
          "name" : "minit",
          "info" : "child 1 of file 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "files",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 0.5897495,
        "_source" : {
          "docid" : 4,
          "parentdocid" : 2,
          "name" : "oribi",
          "info" : "child 2 of file 2"
        }
      }
    ]
```

because minit is child of microsoft, and I want to include all child documents of microsoft.

so on if I search for "minit or primephonic" then it would produce above result plus below

```
      {
        "_index" : "files",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 0.47733158,
        "_source" : {
          "docid" : 5,
          "parentdocid" : 1,
          "name" : "primephonic",
          "info" : "child 1 of file 1"
        }
      }
```

Thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some brainstorming, I'm able to achieve this with help of parent/child relation.

Index and data setup

```
PUT /files
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "docid": { "type": "long" },
        "parentdocid": { "type": "long" },
        "name": {"type":"text"},
        "info": {"type":"text"},
        "parent_relations":{
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "parentdocid": "docid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
POST /files/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{ "parentdocid" : 0, "parent_relations":{"name":"parentdocid"} }
PUT /files/_bulk?routing=1
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{ "docid" : 1, "name": "apple", "info": "file 1", "parent_relations":{"name":"docid","parent":1} }
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{ "docid" : 2, "name": "microsoft", "info": "file 2", "parent_relations":{"name":"docid","parent":1} }
POST /files/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{ "parentdocid" : 1, "parent_relations":{"name":"parentdocid"} }
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{ "parentdocid" : 2, "parent_relations":{"name":"parentdocid"} }
PUT /files/_bulk?routing=4
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{ "docid" : 3, "name": "primephonic", "info": "child 1 of file 1", "parent_relations":{"name":"docid","parent":4} }
PUT /files/_bulk?routing=5
{"index":{"_id":7}}
{ "docid" : 4, "name": "minit", "info": "child 1 of file 2", "parent_relations":{"name":"docid","parent":5} }
{"index":{"_id":8}}
{ "docid" : 5, "name": "oribi", "info": "child 2 of file 2", "parent_relations":{"name":"docid","parent":5} }
```

search query

```
GET /files/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "parentdocid",
      "query": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "docid",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "name": "minit"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result

```
      {
        "_index" : "files",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "5",
        "_source" : {
          "docid" : 4,
          "name" : "minit",
          "info" : "child 1 of file 2",
          "parent_relations" : {
            "name" : "docid",
            "parent" : 5
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "files",
        "_id" : "8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "5",
        "_source" : {
          "docid" : 5,
          "name" : "oribi",
          "info" : "child 2 of file 2",
          "parent_relations" : {
            "name" : "docid",
            "parent" : 5
          }
        }
      }
```

above query satisfy my need.

Please share your thoughts if there is scope of improvement or any other better way.

Thank You

Comment: We can assume this way we can perform subquery in elastic, although it could be expensive, use carefully and only if required.
**SQL verion**
SELECT * FROM files WHERE parentdocid IN (SELECT parentdocid FROM files WHERE name = 'minit')